# Помогите разобраться с куки

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, cookie

Помогите разобраться с куки в браузере.
У меня есть приложение. При первом посещении сайта, я хочу генерировать куки и хранить их в браузере. При обновлении страницы пользователем, я хочу брать его куки и отправлять на backend.

У меня есть HTML код (есть ниже). В нём два блока. Если пользователь посещает сайт в первые, то ему показывается блок с кнопкой "Take a test". Если пользователь был на сайте, то должен показываться блок с кнопкой "Смотреть свои новости".

Эту логику я попытался описать в js коде.
У меня есть window.onload, которая запускает функцию pageInit().

PageInit() проверяет, установлены ли куки в браузере. Я проверяю куки с названием token. Если их нет, то я показываю первый блок HTML. И по нажатию на кнопку "Take A test" сработает запрос fetchNotExistUserPOST(); Он возвратит куки, сгенерированные на бэке и установит их пользователю. Если же куки есть, то показывается второй блок html, где по нажатию на кнопку "Смотреть свои новости" отработает fetchExistUserPOST();

Я добавил код запросов ниже.
Приложу ещё код на backend для принятия этих запросов.

Проблема такая: когда я первый раз захожу на страницу, у меня всё отображается корректно. Показывается первый блок html с кнопкой "Take a test". После нажатия на эту кнопку, у меня генерируются куки и хранятся в браузере. Но при обновлении страницы, всё равно показывается первый html-блок с кнопкой "Take a test".

[image: До нажатия на кнопку Take a test]
[image: Появление куки]
[image: При обновлении страницы всё равно отображается тот же блок, но куки те же]

BACKEND на flask:

```html
@app.route('/not-exist-user', methods=['POST'])
def not_exist_user():
    try:
        data = request.json
        articles = data.get('articles', [])
        
        # Генерация куки
        session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

        json_data = '{"user": "user1", "roles": ["admin", "user"]}'
        insert_data(session_id, json_data)

        # Возврат тех же новостей и куки в ответе
        response_data = {
            "token": session_id,
            "news": articles
        }

         # Создаем объект ответа
        response = make_response(jsonify(response_data))
        # Устанавливаем куки, которая истекает через год
        expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365)
        response.set_cookie('token', value=session_id, expires=expires, httponly=True)

        return response
        return jsonify(response_data), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500


@app.route('/exist-user', methods=['POST'])
def exist_user():
    try:
        data = request.json
        articles = data.get('articles', [])
        
        # Генерация куки
        session_id = "Взять в базе"

        # Возврат тех же новостей и куки в ответе
        response_data = {
            "token": session_id,
            "news": articles
        }

        return jsonify(response_data), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
```

Запросы на фронтэнде:

```js
const fetchExistUserPOST = async () => {
    try {
        // Получение новостей из NEWS API
        const newsResponse = await fetch(EVERYTHING);

        if (newsResponse.ok) {
            const newsJson = await newsResponse.json();
            const newsEverything = newsJson.articles.map(article => ({
                source: article.source,
                author: article.author,
                title: removeInvalidCharacters(article.title),
                description: removeInvalidCharacters(article.description),
                url: article.url,
                urlToImage: article.urlToImage,
                publishedAt: article.publishedAt,
                content: removeInvalidCharacters(article.content)
            }));

            // Получение значения куки sessionId
            const sessionId = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)sessionId\s*=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

            // Теперь отправляем данные на другой backend
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    sessionId: sessionId,
                    answers: [
                        { number: 1, description: 'Answer 1' },
                        { number: 2, description: 'Answer 2' },
                        // Добавьте остальные ответы по аналогии
                    ],
                    articles: newsEverything
                })
            };

            const backendResponse = await fetch('/exist-user', requestOptions);
            if (backendResponse.ok) {
                console.log("POST EXIST USER");
                const responseData = await backendResponse.json();
                console.log('Data successfully sent to the backend');
                console.log(`Your token: "${responseData.token}", news:`, responseData.news);
            } else {
                console.error('Error sending data to the backend:', backendResponse.status, backendResponse.statusText);
            }
        } else {
            console.error(`Error fetching news data: ${newsResponse.status} - ${newsResponse.statusText}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

const fetchNotExistUserPOST = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(EVERYTHING);

        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            const myJson = await response.json();
            const newsEverything = myJson.articles.map(article => ({
                source: article.source,
                author: article.author,
                title: removeInvalidCharacters(article.title),
                description: removeInvalidCharacters(article.description),
                url: article.url,
                urlToImage: article.urlToImage,
                publishedAt: article.publishedAt,
                content: removeInvalidCharacters(article.content)
            }));

            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    articles: newsEverything,
                    answers: [
                        { number: 1, description: 'Answer 1' },
                        { number: 2, description: 'Answer 2' },
                        // Добавьте остальные ответы по аналогии
                    ]
                })
            };

            const backendResponse = await fetch('/not-exist-user', requestOptions);
            if (backendResponse.ok) {
                console.log("POST NOT EXIST USER");
                const responseData = await backendResponse.json();
                console.log('Data successfully sent to the backend');
                console.log(`Your token: "${responseData.token}", news:`, responseData.news);
                console.log(`YoUr SeSsIoN iD: "${responseData.sessionId}"`);
                const expirationDate = new Date();
                expirationDate.setFullYear(expirationDate.getFullYear() + 10);
                document.cookie = `token=${responseData.token}; =${expirationDate.toUTCString()}; path=/`;
            } else {
                console.error('Error sending data to the backend:', backendResponse.status, backendResponse.statusText);
            }
        } else {
            console.error(`Error fetching data: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}
```

Мой фронтенд:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    // fetchHeadlines();
    // fetchRandomCountryNews();
    // checkNewsAsia();
    // fetchNotExistUserPOST();
    // fetchEverythingNewsPUT();
    // fetchExistUserPOST();
    // parserFromQAnswer(button);
    // fetchCategoryNews();
    // fetchScienseNews();
    // fetchTechnologyNews();
    // sortRequest(globalKey);
    pageInit();
    // checkNewsEuarasia();
    // checkNewsNorthAmerica();
    // checkNewsSouthAmerica();
    // checkNewsEurope();
};


function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}

function pageInit() {
    // Проверяем наличие куки в браузере
    const token = getCookie('token');
    const hasTokenCookie = token !== undefined;
    console.log(token);

    // Находим элементы на странице
    const noCookieDiv = document.getElementById('noCookie');
    const yesCookieDiv = document.getElementById('yesCookie');
    const TakeTest = document.getElementById('taketest');
    const showINews = document.getElementById('showINews');

    // Отображаем или скрываем блоки на основе наличия куки
    if (hasTokenCookie) {
        yesCookieDiv.style.display = 'block';
        noCookieDiv.style.display = 'none';
        if (showINews) {
            showINews.addEventListener('click', () => {
                fetchExistUserPOST();
            });
        }
    } else {
        yesCookieDiv.style.display = 'none';
        noCookieDiv.style.display = 'block';

        // Добавляем обработчики для кнопок
        if (TakeTest) {
            TakeTest.addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log("дед умер");
                fetchNotExistUserPOST();
                console.log("дед умер");
                // Здесь должен быть код для parserFromQAnswer, но button не определен
                // parserFromQAnswer(button);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Элемент с ID taketest не найден.');
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div id="noCookie" class="container col-6 mt-5 testBlock">
        <div class="container mt-4 col-8">
            <h5 class="row text-center testText mb-5">
                Would you like to see news to suit your mood today? Answer a few questions to get a news feed that suits
                your preferences.
            </h5>
            <a id="taketest" href="test" class="btn d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 btnTest mb-4">
                TAKE A TEST!
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="yesCookie" class="container col-6 mt-5 testBlock">
        <div class="container mt-4 col-8">
            <h5 class="row text-center testText mb-5">
                Я смотрю, ты прошёл тест. Ну давай, смотри свои новсти
            </h5>
            <a id="showINews" href="test" class="btn d-flex justify-content-center mb-2 btnTest mb-4">
                Смотреть свои новсти
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```